# É possível adicionar um diretório vazio a um repositório Git?

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber se eu posso adicionar um diretório vazio ao meu repositório Git? Se possível, como fazer isso?

Comment: Queres que essa directoria fique vazia para sempre?

Comment: Não, apenas uma dúvida... Se é possível fazer isso.

Comment: @bruno Às vezes é interessante (simplifica o código) que se tenha certeza que uma pasta exista, ainda que não se tenha a princípio nada para colocar nela. Acho pertinente, já tive essa dúvida com outros VCSs.

Comment: Acho que não podemos criar ele vazio, mas dá de deixar ele vazio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação não é possível.

> Can I add empty directories?
>
> Currently the design of the Git index (staging area) only permits
>   files to be listed, and nobody competent enough to make the change to
>   allow empty directories has cared enough about this situation to
>   remedy it. Directories are added automatically when adding files
>   inside them. That is, directories never have to be added to the
>   repository, and are not tracked on their own. You can say "git add
>   " and it will add the files in there. If you really need a
>   directory to exist in checkouts you should create a file in it.
>   .gitignore works well for this purpose (there is also a tool
>   MarkEmptyDirs using the .NET framework which allows you to automate
>   this task); you can leave it empty or fill in the names of files you
>   do not expect to show up in the directory.

Tem no entanto este "hack" que permite atingir quase o que pretendes. Crias um ficheiro com nome `.gitignore` com este conteúdo. Isto impede que sejam criados novos ficheiros na directoria.

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

Comment: Foi justamente isso que tinha acessado agora a pouco :D

Comment: Podemos deixar ele vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma comum de fazer (mais ou menos) isso é adicionar um arquivo em na pasta. É comum ver repositórios com pastas que só tem um arquivo em branco `.gitkeep` dentro.